# How to change the values in an array on python

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

I have the following numpy array in python:

```
[[ True  True  True ...,  True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True ...,  True  True False]
 [ True  True  True ...,  True False  True]
 ..., 
 [ True  True  True ...,  True  True False]
 [ True  True  True ..., False False  True]
 [ True  True  True ...,  True  True  True]]
```

I want to change the values of the array, so that when there are less than three consecutive 'False' values in a row, for those value to be changed to True, and when I have three or more 'False'  consecutive values in a row, for them to be replaced by only one 'False' statement

Basically, I want it to end up looking like this:
before:

```
[[ True  True  True False  True  True]
 [ True  False  True  True  True False]
 [ False False False False]
```

This is the result I want:

```
[[ True  True  True True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True  True False]
```

Any help on how to do this?

Thanks

Comment: `arr[0][0] = False`?

Comment: It would be useful to include a small example showing, say, a 9x9 boolean array and then show what it should look like after the operation.

Comment: When you say "less than three 'False' values in a row" do you mean less than three *consecutive* 'False' values, or can they be anywhere in the row?

Comment: @ajcr yes its three consecutive false values, sorry about that

Comment: @AntonProtopopov I tried making elif statements, but the furthest I got was changing false into true, it was not able to recognise when there were three consecutive false statements

Comment: I thought you wanted that when you had three or more they remain unchanged?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Sorry I cleared that up now. I'm new to this website and coding, so I'm having some issues with it

Comment: You want to change the size of your array?

Comment: Depending on the actual use case (I think I don't get your point) the scipy function [binary_fill_holes](scipy.ndimage.morphology.binary_fill_holes) cloud be your friend.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham The end result would be a change in the size of the array. I just want to change where there are less than 3  consecutive False statements in my array to True statements. And also change where there are more than 3 consecutive False statements into only one False statement

Answer (score 0):

Since you are analyzing each row independently, and a row's size may change, forget about this being an array.  It is a list of arrays (or lists).  The solution strategy is to then write a function that takes a row, transforms it, and returns a new list.

```
def process_arow(arow):
   <to be determined>
   return new_row

[process_arow(arow) for arow in rows]
```

As for the row processing, my impression is that you just need to iterate through it, passing either a True, False, or nothing on.  At first glance I don't much point in treating it as an array.  Maybe after we get it working we could cast it as an (parallel) operation, but it is usually easier to develop an idea iteratively.

A first stab:

```
def subfn(newrow,cnt):
    if cnt>2:
        cnt=1
    for i in range(cnt):
        newrow.append(False)
    return newrow

def process_arow(arow):
    newrow=[]; cnt=0
    for r in arow:
        if r:
            newrow=subfn(newrow,cnt)
            cnt=0    
            newrow.append(True)                      
        else:                  
             cnt += 1          
    return subfn(newrow,cnt)
```

testing:

```
In [448]: process_arow([True, True,False, False])
Out[448]: [True, True, False, False]

In [449]: process_arow([True, True,False, False,False])
Out[449]: [True, True, False]

In [450]: process_arow([True, True,False, False,False,True])
Out[450]: [True, True, False, True]

In [451]: process_arow([True, True,False,False,False,True,False,False])
Out[451]: [True, True, False, True, False, False]
```